# Retrieving and Posting data from/to a related table in Django APIView

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am working on a Django application with two Models.

1. Messages - that contain twitter style messages
2. Feedback - response to messages including comments, likes, dislikes

I am writing APIView for Feedback, but it is not GETing or POSTing the relevant messages even though I can browse through the admin panel.

The code is as follows:

**Models:**

```
class Messages(models.Model):
postIdentifier = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
message = models.TextField(null=False)

class Feedback(models.Model):
isLiked = models.BooleanField(null=True)
isDisliked = models.BooleanField(null=True)
comment = models.TextField(null=True)
post = models.ForeignKey(Messages, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Serializers:**

```
class MessagesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
model = Messages
fields = ['postIdentifier', 'title', 'message']

class FeedbackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
message = MessagesSerializer()
class Meta:
model = Feedback
fields = ['isLiked', 'isDisliked', 'comment', 'post']
```

**APIView for Feedback model**

```
def get(self, request, id):

        related_message_object = Messages.objects.filter(id)
        feedback = Feedback.objects.filter('post'= related_message_object)
        serializer = FeedbackSerializer(feedback)
        return Response({
            'data': serializer.data
            })

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        serializer = FeedbackSerializer(data= request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({
                'message': 'Feedback data posted successfully!',
                'data': serializer.data
                })
```

The URLPattern for the feedback is

*path('feedback/< id >/', FeedbackAPIView.as_view()),*
#I am aware of spaces here on either side of id as I am unable to post the id with brackets on.

I am going through the rest_framework documentation, but I can not find relevant documentation with regard to the problem. Can anyone kindly point out my mistake in the get() method of FeedbackAPIView. I am hoping to achieve that when I browse feedback/2/ I want to see feedback relavant to Message with postIdentifier = 2. Any feedback is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the feedback resource url is `path('feedback/< id >/', FeedbackAPIView.as_view())`,

then at `def get(self, request, id):`   you should filter feedback by `id` :

`feedback = Feedback.objects.filter(id=id).first()`

Comment: thanks a lot for your input. Really appreciate it!